# enabling modules for a kernel

Tags: linux, centos, xen, kvm-virtualization, kernel

I have a KVM/XEN VPS and would like to enable the following modules:

```
ipt_LOG
ipt_multiport
ipt_state
ipt_limit
ipt_recent
ipt_owner
iptable_nat
tun/tap
iptable_nat
ipt_MASQUERADE
ipt_POSTROUTING
PPTP
IPSec
L2TP
```

Do I need to recompile a kernel and boot into it? or can i just do something to load the modules up. im creating a vpn box. openvz was too limiting.

Comment: Well, which is it? KVM or Xen?

Comment: XEN. I was under impression both are basically the same

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if this VPS is running a Xen kernel from the host or which provider you are using.  Most XEN VPS providers utilize a kernel (selected from a list) in a web interface in the hosting providers web interface.  To use a kernel module that is not already present in the kernel will likely require running a pv-grub configuration.  Your provider likely has documentation for this.

A good indication of how the running kernel was built is looking at config.gz

```
zcat /proc/config.gz
```

Also, if you type lsmod and nothing shows up, this kernel was not likely built to support additional kernel modules.

You may also wish to look through the community forum of the VPS provider that you use.  They often have a FAQ or forum that covers provider specific limitations and workarounds.